# Uppercase to Lower only in the first line of a text file?

Tags: shell, scripting

I must convert upper case to lower case only in the first line, and the changes must affect the text, not only print a good result.

Example of text:
AzE
B
C

Result:
aze
B
C

Thank you

Comment: I find the question not understandable, but from the example you give, I assume that you have a line with 3 words, and want the first and last word be turned into lower case. Is this correct?

Comment: I want to convert the first line on lowercase in a text file

Comment: Maybe you should then fix your posting to reflect this desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a file named `file` exists in the current directory, and assuming that the content of that file is:

```
AzE
B
C
```

and assuming that you want to convert to lower case only the first line, as the title of the question says, the following command will print what you want:

```
head -n1 file |tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'; tail -n -2 file
```

the result is:

```
aze
B
C
```

The first line of the file is extracted by `head`, and filtered via `tr`; the result is output on the screen. Then, the `tail` command is used to print the rest of the file.

If you want to write to another file, you must execute the two commands as a single one, and redirect the whole "compound" command, like this:

```
(head -n1 file |tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'; tail -n -2 file) >file2
```

Remember to *not* redirect to the same file you are reading... it will not work.

Hope this helps.